# Facebook login notification approval?

Tags: facebook, security

Apparently my Facebook login notification emails me if someone has logged-in to my account, without any approval link/code in the email they send me.

Is that really the way it's supposed to work?

Because if it is, then I think it's quite useless since the unauthorized user already gained access anyway.

Or, does it have an approval link/code that I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The email messages you are talking about are sent as *login notifications* and it really is how they're supposed to work. It is a separate feature from *login approvals*, which require to enter a code received by SMS.

[image: Facebook Account -> Security]

Comment: well it seems that I do not have Login approvals maybe because I am not from the US. The clear things up.

Comment: I'm not from the US either, and the Facebook support pages do not mention any country restrictions.

Comment: Apparently, I do not have it but thanks.