# Has Facebook disabled Login Approvals?

Tags: facebook, security, multi-factor-auth

I have recently discovered that login approvals on Facebook is no longer available:

[image]

Compare this with @gravity's screenshot from this [answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/23221/310):

[image]

Is there anything special that I'll have to ask my friend to do get Login approvals? Or is this something which Facebook has disabled? Can I enable it?

(Note: I *do* have Login approvals enabled and I think it's because I started using it before the feature was disabled/removed.)

Comment: I was not able to find any official or unofficial announcements at all, there is something seriously wrong. I have deleted my answer.

Comment: @Sathya, Login approval needs to send you SMS every time you login from unknown device. As in India, sending mass SMS has been restricted, you think that's why they removed it? The option is also not their in my profile.

Comment: @Bibhas Don't think so. Login notifications are still there, and these make use of SMS notifications as well. So I don't believe that's the reason.

Comment: @Bibhas When Google can send codes to India for two-step verification, then why not Facebook? You guess is wrong for sure.

Comment: It's back again now for me in the UK.

Answer (score 2):

It's not disabled in general; I still have it on my account - did Facebook's attempts to send you SMS recently fail or something? Check your account settings to check if your mobile phone number is correct and able to receive SMS

Comment: please read my post again - `I do have Login approvals enabled...Is there anything special that I'll have to ask my friend to do get Login approvals`

Comment: Then change my answer to 'your friends' instead of 'you' - i think it may be dependent on having a valid, contactable-by-Facebook mobile number on the account

Answer (score 1):

Yes, login approvals have been disabled by facebook, as new features and shortcuts are being added.

Also, if you try the same phone number on multiple accounts then they're being disabled but as soon as possible they will be enabled soon.

Another method is, if they have been automatically disabled from your account then try to create a strong password containing numeric and alpha numeric characters.

Check this site: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0RCsHJfHL_4 for info.

Answer (score 1):

Facebook login approvals seem to be renabled on my account, and judging by the [Help Pages](https://www.facebook.com/help/148233965247823) seems to be back up in general.

A Facebook employee also mentions that it should [be rolled out to all accounts soon](https://twitter.com/gmanka/status/311057030418927616).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. This can be resolved by using a VPN like Spotflux. Do a hard refresh on the Security settings page, and you should see Login approvals in the list. It's interesting to note that as soon as you return to an Indian IP address, the option vanishes again. Access to Login approvals seems to be limited geographically. But once you enable it, it should work normally.